# Windows phone 7.1 emulator doesn't work

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I have to write a small app for the wp 7.1 and the requires to debug it from time to time. But the windows phone emulator doesn't work on my PC (**Windows 7 32 bit, RAM 4GB, Video ATI Radeon mobility 3430**). Every time I'm trying to run the emulator, I get this message:
[image]

I just updated the driver, restarted my PC. But still it doesn't work. I saw several topics about similar problem, but those advises didn't work for me.
Could you, please, tell me where could be the problem?

Comment: I know that this happens if you are running in a virtual computer.. You should still be able to debug against a physical phone btw.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, this is not a virtual machine. The fun thing is, the emulator worked before on this PC. Since that moment the configuration of the PC wasn't changed at all.